# Cucumber:Extent report is not getting generated in the output folder

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, cucumber, extentreports

I am using extent reports in Cucumber with jUnit and its working fine for me but whenever my tests run is completed then extent report is not getting generated in my project output folder.

Below is My runner Class

```
 package mortgage.runners;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;   
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"},
features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
glue = {"mortgage.stepdefinitions"},
// dryRun = true,
tags = "@RegressionTest",
monochrome = true) 

public class CukesRunner {    
}
```

I have added following maven dependencies in the pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
           <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>  

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```

Below is the error i'm getting for the reporting part and also i'm not seeing any html file getting generated in the output/target folder i tried even updating extent report version to 4.0.7 but still the same issue target folder is empty

> [java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.aventstack.extentreports.utils.ExceptionUtil.getExceptionHeadline(ExceptionUtil.java:25)
>   at
>   com.aventstack.extentreports.model.ExceptionInfo.(ExceptionInfo.java:19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaOTK.png)

Comment: Did you initialize the report using ExtentService ?

Comment: Yes Under Src/test/resources i initialized it

extent.reporter.html.start=true
extent.reporter.logger.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.start=true

extent.reporter.html.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.logger.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.spark.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml

extent.reporter.html.out=test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html
extent.reporter.logger.out=test-output/Logger
extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/Spark

screenshot.dir=test-output/

Comment: As per the config file, you should see output under this folder -- > test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.htm.   you may be looking at wrong folder ---> output/target folder

Comment: Even that folder is empty

Comment: Try setting the folder path in the global hooks. i.e  System.setProperty("extent.reporter.html.out", "test-output/HtmlReport/");

Answer (score 0):

try by removing the value for config & keep it as empty, as adapter does not require the config file. pass like 'extent.reporter.html.config='